# How Client talking to other client java

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp

I'm currently learning about TCP in Java. My latest code is connect multi client to 1 server. I did that like everytime a new client appear I create a new GUI of server to handle that client. 
I try to think how server can talking to 2 client at the same time and client itself can read the information both from server and other client.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: I'm confused: "new GUI of server"

Comment: @Mikey i mean a new Frame will popup to handle a new client. Of course i only have 1 server.

Comment: Thats what i'm confused about: why is a GUI needed for server to handle TCP connections? But OK.. If you want clients communicate throught server those Frames have to reference some common object.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is connection-oriented protocol designed for data exchange between **two** sides. TCP client can talk only with TCP server, but not with another TCP client. So if you need client-to-client communication then you could transfer data from the first client firstly to the server. Server should know somehow that that data are for the second client and transfer them to it.

Another way would be to establish separate TCP connections between each peer.

Comment: yes i mean client communicate with client with server of course. And i wonder how can server can accept each client thread data and send to the other.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is your difficulty with it? Do you have any working code for client<->server communication?